# Beautifulsoup - How to scrape key values inside a div data-page / data-v-app?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Been learning web scraping and have done a few projects using python & beautifulsoup - so far so good. However data-page / data-v-app is something I haven't come across. The info I need sits inside a <div data-page that looks similar to JSON, but it doesn't appear to be. It finishes with data-v-app. Any idea how to scrape this? I'm only after a few key & value pairs.
[See the screenshot here which will make more sense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSmCT.png), thank you!

Comment: On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the minimal information of question, you have to [access the attribute value via `get()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) and [decode it to JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html):

```
import json
...
json.loads(soup.select_one('#app').get('data-page'))
```